# AngularJS: Databinding between Arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, data-binding

Given an Array `sourceArray` I would like to create a `targetArray` that depends on the entries of the first one. This means that the created Array should contain an entry for each of the source-entries and is updated whenever `sourceArray` changes. However modifying the `targetArray` should never update the source.

This [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nhM4b1bhTcQGjt1BvLe8?p=preview) kind of works as long as `sourceArray` is static. As soon as you start to modify the source-entries, it obviously won't update the target properly because i am lacking a proper databinding mechanism.

Do i need to update `targetArray` manually by observing `sourceArray` or is there any kind of 1-way-databinding mechanism implemented by Angular which i can use to keep two arrays synchronized?

Comment: It's best if you avoid extra $watches as some of the answers here have shown. It's a workaround but on the cost of performance when scaling. Angular _does_ provides one way data binding. Here's a link if you'd like to know how it works https://toddmotto.com/one-way-data-binding-in-angular-1-5/

Answer (score 3):

As Pritam said. You should Use $watch. But must bind the Collection to it, in order to make it work. And inside the watch merge the arrays.

Find this working sample:

```
$scope.$watchCollection(angular.bind(this, function () {
    return this.sourceArray;}), function (newVal, oldVal) {

      var arr = [];
      for(var i in vm.sourceArray){
         var shared = false;
         for (var j in vm.targetArray)
             if (vm.targetArray[j].id == vm.sourceArray[i].id) {
                 shared = true;
                 break; 
             }
         if(!shared) arr.push(vm.sourceArray[i])
      }
      console.log(arr);
      vm.targetArray = vm.targetArray.concat(arr);
    },true);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/E2inRLtwfWnb1VBymNNl?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$watch`. And then add the necessary function.

You can look [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-watch-angularjs/) and the [official documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

> $watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]); Registers a
>   listener callback to be executed whenever the watchExpression changes.
>
> The watchExpression is called on every call to $digest() and should
>   return the value that will be watched. (watchExpression should not
>   change its value when executed multiple times with the same input
>   because it may be executed multiple times by $digest(). That is,
>   watchExpression should be idempotent.) The listener is called only
>   when the value from the current watchExpression and the previous call
>   to watchExpression are not equal (with the exception of the initial
>   run, see below). Inequality is determined according to reference
>   inequality, strict comparison via the !== Javascript operator, unless
>   objectEquality == true (see next point) When objectEquality == true,
>   inequality of the watchExpression is determined according to the
>   angular.equals function. To save the value of the object for later
>   comparison, the angular.copy function is used. This therefore means
>   that watching complex objects will have adverse memory and performance
>   implications. This should not be used to watch for changes in objects
>   that are or contain File objects due to limitations with angular.copy.
>   The watch listener may change the model, which may trigger other
>   listeners to fire. This is achieved by rerunning the watchers until no
>   changes are detected. The rerun iteration limit is 10 to prevent an
>   infinite loop deadlock. If you want to be notified whenever $digest is
>   called, you can register a watchExpression function with no listener.
>   (Be prepared for multiple calls to your watchExpression because it
>   will execute multiple times in a single $digest cycle if a change is
>   detected.)
>
> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is
>   called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In
>   rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when
>   the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario
>   within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If
>   these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due
>   to initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $watch expression.

Here is another way:-(download underscore.js or CDN)

http://plnkr.co/edit/hrOrEdaQ0M7wEgWlRHlO?p=preview

1. angular.js copy (angular.copy()) method.
2. underscore.js extend method.

   ```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
       app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
           var vm = this;
           vm.sourceArray = [{id: '0', name: 'someObject'}, {id: '1', name: 'anotherObject'}];
           vm.targetArray = angular.copy(vm.sourceArray);
          // angular.copy(vm.sourceArray, vm.targetArray);
           vm.push = function(){
             let found = false;
             angular.forEach(vm.sourceArray, function(el){
               if (el.id === vm.id){
                 el.name = vm.name;
                 found = true;
               }
             });
             if (!found){
               vm.sourceArray.push({id: vm.id, name: vm.name});
              _.extend(vm.targetArray, vm.sourceArray);
             }

       };



   vm.pushTarget = function(){
     let found = false;
     angular.forEach(vm.targetArray, function(el){
       if (el.id === vm.id1){
         el.name = vm.name1;
         found = true;
       }
     });
     if (!found){
       console.log({id: vm.id, name: vm.name})
       vm.targetArray.push({id: vm.id1, name: vm.name1});  
     }

   };
   ```

   });

you can get underscore.js code:-

```
_.extend = createAssigner(_.allKeys);

// An internal function for creating assigner functions.
var createAssigner = function(keysFunc, undefinedOnly) {
    return function(obj) {
      var length = arguments.length;
      if (length < 2 || obj == null) return obj;
      for (var index = 1; index < length; index++) {
        var source = arguments[index],
            keys = keysFunc(source),
            l = keys.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
          var key = keys[i];
          if (!undefinedOnly || obj[key] === void 0) obj[key] = source[key];
        }
      }
      return obj;
    };
  };

  // Retrieve all the property names of an object.
  _.allKeys = function(obj) {
    if (!_.isObject(obj)) return [];
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in obj) keys.push(key);
    // Ahem, IE < 9.
    if (hasEnumBug) collectNonEnumProps(obj, keys);
    return keys;
  };

   // Extend a given object with all the properties in passed-in object(s).
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet I made. Note when changing source array both arrays are affected, however when you change only the target the source stays intact.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.sourceArray = [];
    vm.source = '["change me!",{"a":3},[100]]';

    $scope.$watch('vm.source', function(newVal) {
      try {
        vm.sourceArray = JSON.parse(newVal);
        vm.target = newVal;
        vm.serr = null;
      } catch (e) {
        vm.serr = 'Invalid JSON';
      }
    });
  
  $scope.$watch('vm.target', function(newVal) {
      try {
        vm.targetArray = JSON.parse(newVal);
        vm.terr = null;
      } catch (e) {
        vm.terr = 'Invalid JSON';
      }
    });

    //Copy whole array on change
    $scope.$watch('vm.sourceArray', function(newVal) {
      vm.targetArray = angular.copy(newVal);
    }, true);

    return this;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
  <span>Change the inputs one at a time to see the changes take effect</span>
  <h5>Source:</h5>
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.source" ng-model-options="{debounce: 300}" placeholder="Enter json formatted string for source array"><span>{{vm.serr}}</span>
  <div>Model: {{vm.sourceArray|json:null:2}}</div>
  <br>
  <h5>Target:</h5>
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.target" ng-model-options="{debounce: 300}" placeholder="Enter json formatted string for source array"><span>{{vm.terr}}</span>
  <div>Model: {{vm.targetArray|json:null:2}}</div>
</div>
```